# Unable install Xamarin Firebase - Common 32.961.0 to xamarin.forms solution

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

Unable to add Xamarin Firebase - Common NuGet to my xamarin.forms solution. Is Firebase Nuget compatible for Xamarin.forms solution?  Can I use FCM in xamarin.forms project?

- Xamarin.Android Version: Xamarin 6.1.3, MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0
- Operating System & Version: Windows 10
- Steps to Reproduce:

  1. Create a new xamarin.forms solution and try to add Firebase package

Package Console

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Common.32.961.0' with respect to project 'Fire.Droid', targeting 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Common.32.961.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Unable to find a version of 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' that is compatible with 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable 23.3.0 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 23.3.0 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 23.3.0 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 23.3.0 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView 23.3.0 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable 23.3.0 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.180 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 32.961.0 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (>= 24.2.1)'.
```

Comment: You're right, we met the same issue, I think the best we can do is submitting this issue to xamarin [here](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Updated to newest release of xamarin 4.2.2.11
That resolved the issue.